# Connot use \begin{picture} in tex

Tags: xetex, pdf, inkscape

Found the problem exactly, the tex connot recognize `\end{picture}`,I cannot use any

```
\begin{picture}
....
\end{pictue}
```

in tex code.

A sample

```
    ....
         \begin{figure}
              \centering
              \def\svgwidth{0.6\columnwidth}
              \begin{picture}(1,0.73650159)%
                  \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength]{image.pdf}}%
              \end{picture}%
              \caption{00}
              \label{intro_e1}
          \end{figure}
      \end{enumerate}
```

ERROR:

`Paragraph ended before \@picture was complete. <to be read again>`  
`\begin{picture} on input line 103 ended by \end{enumerate}.`

These are picture-related package in my `.sty`, is there conflict?

```
%-
%-> Figure environment support
%-
\RequirePackage{multirow}
\RequirePackage{makecell}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}% packages for including graphics
\RequirePackage{setspace}
\RequirePackage[
    font={small, singlespacing, stretch=1.1},
    parskip=0pt,
    skip=0pt,
    labelsep=space,
    justification=centering
]{caption}% options: [margin=10pt,labelfont=bf]
% \captionsetup{font={stretch=1.1}}
\RequirePackage{subcaption}% package for subfigures
\RequirePackage[list=off]{bicaption}% package for binary captions
\captionsetup[figure][bi-first]{format=hang,hangindent=-0.5em}%
\captionsetup[figure][bi-second]{format=hang,hangindent=-2em,name=Fig.}%
\captionsetup[table][bi-first]{format=hang,hangindent=-0.5em}%
\captionsetup[table][bi-second]{format=hang,hangindent=-2em,name=Table}%
\RequirePackage[section]{placeins}% prevent floats from being moved over section
%-
%-> Page layout and spacing
%-
\ifartx@geometry% enable geometry to redefine page layout
    \RequirePackage{geometry}% page layout
```

---

#### The below are outdated issues, ignore these

I have set`\graphicspath{{Img/}}`in `.sty`
and set

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{import}
```

If I use code

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \def\svgwidth{0.6\columnwidth}
    \import{Img/}{intro_example0.pdf_tex}
%or \input{Img/intro_example0.pdf_tex}
    \caption{origin}
    \label{fig:intro_e0}
\end{figure}
```

ERROR:`File ended while scanning use of \@picture. ^^I\import{Img/}{intro_example0.pdf_tex}`

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \def\svgwidth{0.6\columnwidth}
    \input{intro_example0.pdf_tex}
    \caption{origin}
    \label{fig:intro_e0}
\end{figure}
```

ERROR:`` File `intro_example0.pdf_tex' not found. ^^I\input{intro_example0.pdf_tex} ``

If I use code after moving .pdf_tex to project path

```
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \centering
    \def\svgwidth{\columnwidth}
    \import{intro_example0.pdf_tex}
    \caption{orign}
    \label{fig:intro_e0}
\end{figure}
```

ERROR:  `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]. ^^I\caption`

```
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \centering
    \def\svgwidth{\columnwidth}
    \input{intro_example0.pdf_tex}
    \caption{orign}
    \label{fig:intro_e0}
\end{figure}
```

ERROR:`File ended while scanning use of \@picture. ^^I\input{intro_example0.pdf_tex}`

Meanwhile the `.jpg` work normally,like

```
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.40\textwidth]{tc_q_criteria}
    \bicaption{Q}
    \label{fig:tc_q_criteria0}
\end{figure}
```

can display normally

How to input `.pdf_tex` file from subfolder?

I seem to be unable to import normally from root folder

---

A example that could display normally

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \def\svgwidth{\columnwidth}
        \input{intro_example0.pdf_tex}
        \caption{orign}
        \label{intro_e0}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

my tex

```
\documentclass[printcopy,windows]{Style/neuthesis}%
\usepackage[bibtex,myhdr,table,list,geometry]{Style/artratex}
\usepackage{Style/artracom}% user defined commands
\def\alltex{}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \def\svgwidth{\columnwidth}
        \input{intro_example0.pdf_tex}
        \caption{origin}
        \label{fig:intro_e0}
    \end{figure}

.....
\end{document}
ERROR:File ended while scanning use of \@picture. ^^I^^I\input{intro_example0.pdf_tex}
```

Comment: Did you also try to use `\input{Img/intro_example0.pdf_tex}`? Did you try to import the file directly from your project path? The error message looks like `intro_example0.pdf_tex` is buggy.

Comment: @ mrpiggi Have tried and didn't work, error as shown above

Comment: So then check `intro_example0.pdf_tex` as this is probably the source of your problem

Comment: @mrpiggi Looks like so, but this `.pdf_tex` can display normally in the other tex

Comment: Since I don't have a crystal ball at hand right now, you'll have to create a MWE to get appropriate help.

Comment: @mrpiggi  Looks like so, it can display normally in a simple example, my tex strcture is complicated, what could go wrong

Comment: well, next step would be to move `intro_example0.pdf` and `intro_example0.pdf_tex` in a subfolder and try again. maybe package `svg` is also an option. obviously your issue is related to your custom class/packages. You can only help yourself...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122499/discussion-between-maple-and-mrpiggi).

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what's inside the `picture` environment, but I'm pretty sure you don't want to use it. The LaTeX `picture` environment is an older primitive drawing environment that uses special fonts to draw lines, circles and quarter circles and has required arguments to specify the size of the space to be reserved for the picture.

Also, it's better to (a) ask one question per post and (2) not edit the question other than to clarify.

Comment: Added a sample and exact error, use `picture` becasue the `.pdf_tex` file exported by inkscape include code `\begin{picture}`.And thank you for your suggestion, I will pay attention next time